# Failed deployment on Polygon Mainnet "Migrations" -- Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent

Tags: blockchain, polygon, smartcontracts, truffle, alchemy-web3

I have been facing an issue while deploying to polygon mainnet while there are no issues while deploying to polygon mumbai testnet.

The issue I am facing is:

```
   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
transaction hash:    0x51f6e8364e0d640d4c94199e470d2060561eb98c13bafb3291ee229725eb394b

Error:   Deployment Failed 

"Migrations" -- Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!.
```

With truffle config as follows:

```
polygon: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          REACT_APP_MNEMONIC,
          https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${REACT_APP_ALCHEMY_API_KEY}
        ),
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
      network_id: 137,
      gas: 3700000,
      gasPrice: 300000000000,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 4000,
      skipDryRun: true,
    },
```

(I have also tried using vpn, various gas and gas prices, changing https to wss, putting different timeoutBlocks)